# Reference to response of async callback bad practice?

Tags: gwt

Today I saw a method in our GWT code Like below:

```
public Map< String, ResponseObject > getResponse( RequestObject requestObject ) {
    remoteServiceAsync = GWT.create( RemoteServce.class );
    final Map< String, ResponseObject > responseReference = new HashMap< String, ResponseObject >();

    remoteServiceAsync.doServerCall( requestObject, new AsyncCallback< ResponseObject >() {
      public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
         // TODO: Do something with errors.
      }

      public void onSuccess( ResponseObject response ) {
        responseReference.put( "value", response );
      }
    } );

    return( responseReference );
};
```

I think,this is a very bad practice. What do you think about this code? Does it work on all browsers, is it a "`valid`" option to read `data`? I have to mention that the data is accessed late in program, so there is no lack of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really bad practice to return that `Hashmap` .It completely breaks the `RPC advantages`.

In that method Immediately it returns an `empty hash-map` and later on  a value inserted into that `Map` ,which has no use.

And initializing also

not even checking `(remoteServiceAsync!=null)` for the below line

```
remoteServiceAsync = GWT.create( RemoteServce.class );
```

So it will initialize for each call.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 Points to highlight here -

1) We dont know when async call returns, So, we can use return statements to return the object returned from the RPC. So, responseReference will always be empty.

2) We no need to create RPC instance every time we need to fire an async call. So Singleton pattern is recommended for this type of scenarios.

Your code snippet can be refactorred as follows -

```
ServiceAsync serviceasync = null;

getServiceAsync()
{
     if(serviceAsync == null)
     {
         serviceAsync = GWT.create( RemoteServce.class );
     }
     return serviceAsync;
}

AsynCallBack asyncCallBack;

getAsyncCallBack()
{
      if(asynvCallback != null)
      {
           return asyncCallback;
      }
      return new AsyncCallback< ResponseObject >() 
            {
                  public void onFailure(Throwable caught) 
                  {
                       // TODO: Do something with errors.
                  }

                   public void onSuccess( ResponseObject response ) 
                   {
                        // Do processing here with the response object ...
                   }
            } );    
}
```

Now where ever getResponse() method is called replace that method call with do the following -

```
getServiceAsync().doServerCall( requestObject, getAsyncCallBack() );
```

So, there will be only one service instance and also one asyncCallBack instance. Creation of multiple objects is avoided and hence adds to performance.